What are the VDDSD, VLXSD, and VFBSD pins?
On the STM32WB09KEV, and on MCUs in general, what do the VDDSD, VLXSD, and VFBSD pins mean.
I can see that they have something to do with SMPS (input/output, ground and output), but what do they actually do, and how to I connect them if I'm not using SMPS.

What does the datasheet say they are? (Look at the pin assignment table)

I've put it in the question: "SMPS (input/output, ground and output)", my question refers to what do they do, not what they mean.

"MCUs in general" do not have pins with these labels. As for the STM32WB09 and similar MCUs with SMPS functionality built-in - what in particular is unclear from the descriptions given in the datasheet, for example: "VDDSD: 1.7-3.6 battery voltage
input"?

Try section 3.8.1.

I don't actually see where they describe required values for it, at least at a glance. A perusal of all documentation seems in order, and failing that, copying parts from a reference design.

SMPS means "switch mode power supply". And in your case, the MCU integrates such functionality. That's not an overly common feature, but some microcontrollers have similar functionality with different pin names.
What they actually do: well, ground connects to ground. For the rest, you will have to refer to the datasheet, or device manual, or user guide, whichever shows explicitly what kind of components you can attach to these pins and which kinds of power supply architectures you can build from that.
So, my guess is as good as yours: I would open up the documentation, find the schematic where they show that, look at how they connect inductors, capacitors and/or transistors, and post a screenshot of it in the answer. That's of no use to you – you can look this up yourself as easily :) It might not be in the datasheet, as said, but in one of the other documents.

In the datasheet, it shows what all these pins do:

Source: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32wb09ke.pdf
